# Check for duplicates before insertion in Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new to Firebase and I trying to implement it into an Android application. It was all going well until now. I have to check the records for duplicates before inserting them and even after the tons of tutorials I watched online I can't figure it out.

I tried with rules, but apparently I was not able to write them down in a way they would work. I tried with `push()`, but this was not working either.

At the moment this is the code that I have:

```
private void updateDatabase(String year, String courseOfStudent, String workshopGroup, String day, String time, String lecture){
    try{
        mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child("course-of-student").setValue(courseOfStudent);
        mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child("year").setValue(year);
        mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child(year).child("workshop-group").setValue(workshopGroup);
        mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child(year).child(workshopGroup).child("day").setValue(day);
        mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child(year).child(workshopGroup).child(day).child("time").setValue(time);
        mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child(year).child(workshopGroup).child(day).child(time).child("lecture").setValue(lecture);}
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Internal error occurred, please try again.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

And the rules from the Firebase console:

```
 {
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "auth != null",
      "course-of-student": {
        "year": {
          "workshop-group": {
            "day":{              
              "time": {
                ".write": "!data.exists()"
              }              
            }
          }
        }
      }
  }
}
```

As of now what happens is that if there is a lecture detail at a specific time and I try to create a new record for this time the previous one gets overwritten. I want to reject this and display a message instead.

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, add "ListenerForSingleValueEvent", and only then save the data in Firebase (if not exist..)
For example:

```
mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
     if(!(snapshot.child("year").exist))
    mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child("year").setValue(year);
   else
   Toast.maketext....."year exist.."

     if(!(snapshot.child(year).child("workshop-group").exist))
    mDatabase.child("student-timetables").child(courseOfStudent).child(year).child("workshop-group").setValue(workshopGroup);
   else
   Toast.maketext....."workshopGroup exist.."
    }
}
```

Comment: you, sir, saved the day! it's been hours that I was fighting with this :)

Comment: @Phantomazi Keep in mind that this solution is prone to race conditions - the snapshot might not exist when you're checking it with `if (...)` but can be created just after but before setting the value with `.setValue()`.