# Android Firebase - Check Duplicate

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```
private void examineData() {
  final String labelnum = "microbe A";
  databaseReference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
      if (!dataSnapshot.child(labelnum).exists()) {
        Toast.makeText(AddMicrobe.this, "Data Does Not Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      } else {
        Toast.makeText(AddMicrobe.this, "Data Exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
  });
}
```

[image]

I refered  [Check for duplicates before insertion in Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40241559/check-for-duplicates-before-insertion-in-firebase) before.. I do not understand how it trace.. 

How to check the "microbeA" already exist? I doing it wrong.. the code does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using `.child(labelnum)` in which `labelnum` is initialized with the value of `microbe A`, you are checking if the key `microbe A` exists. But this not what you want. Using this code you are not checking if the value of `labelnum` key is `microbe A`.

To solve this, you need to check if the value of the `labelnum` key is `microbe A`. So please use the following line of code:

```
!dataSnapshot.child("labelnum").equals("microbe A")
```